# How do I plot a point off the x axis scale on Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

As an example, I have the following data (missing values and one that deviates from the 0-100 scale) that I'd like to plot as a line graph. I'd like the x-axis scale to read 0-100 in 10 increments of 10, and the data point for 61.9 to plot a little to the right of 60, however you can see that the x axis reads 60, 61.9, 70, in equal increments.

[My data and graph with the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDeEE.png)

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange the data as follows and plot the graph as usual (You needn't necessarily put those gaps in between readings). You will get a graph like this.

[image]

In the above graph, the X-axis is formatted automatically with an increment of 20, all the way upto 120.

Now, to plot the X-axis with an equal increment of 10 upto 100, follow the following method:

- *Left click* on any value in the x-axis to select that particular axis of your graph. Now *right click* anywhere on the selected portion to get a menu like this:

[image]

- Click on `Format Axis` which will open this up:

[image]

- After clicking the radio button that says `Fixed`, change the values of `Maximum` and `Major Unit` to `100` and `10` respectively, as marked in red and click `Close`

[image]

- That's it. You'll have it. See this:

[image]

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. (Can't believe I never thanked you before, how rude of me. End of year stress and all that.)

Comment: Glad that it helped :)